# What does the children function in tree-seq do

Tags: clojure

In clojure standard library there is function `tree-seq` which does depth-first traversal on a sequence.

`(tree-seq branch? children root)`

The branch parameter checks for terminal nodes, how ever what does the children function do?

According to the docs `children must be a fn of one arg that returns a sequence of the children`

In `flatten`, tree-seq is used as follows `(tree-seq sequential? seq x)`. However if you do `(seq 1)` then it throws an IllegalArgumentException.

When and how is the children function used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tree-seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq)'s `branch?` function checks if a parameter is a branch, not if it's a terminal node. A branch has leaf nodes, a terminal node is a leaf node.

If we have a branch the `children` functions should return the wanted leaf nodes.

In the case of `flatten`'s `(tree-seq sequential? seq x)`  a branch is checked with `sequential?` and children of a branch are returned via `seq`.

E.g., `(sequential? [1 2 3 4]) ;; => true`, and the children via `(seq [1 2 3 4]) ;; => (1 2 3 4)`. And for a leaf node `(sequential? 1) => false`, and we terminate.